# What are the model parameters in PCA?

Tags: pca

I've been asked to report the number of parameters to be learned in a PCA model. This [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17746) implies that parameters do exist in PCA, but does not explain. Software packages often report the number of parameters, but do not document what those parameters *are*.

What *are* the parameters in a PCA model? Subsidiary question: how many parameters are there?

To be clear - I am not asking about model hyperparameters.

Comment: What do you mean by a PCA model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an algebra point of view PCA is a base change. You can write the transformation as:

$$ T = XW $$

Where $X$ is an nxp matrix (n instance, p features) and $W$ is a pxp 'weight' matrix (whose columns are eigenvectors of $X^TX$ - translating one base to another). Hence the general PCA has $p^2$ coefficients.

You can also reduce the space to m dimensions and use :

$$ T = XW_m $$

Where $W_m$ is a weight matrix constituted of m first columns of $W$. $W_m$ is a pxm weight matrix and has pxm coefficients (or easier to understand : mxp coefficients, that is number of dimension kept and parameters needed to express the new base vector in terms of the initial base). In the case of a projection onto 2 dimensions you will have 2p coefficients.

Comment: So a PCA of rank m, over p-dimensional data has m*p parameters, and these parameters are the coefficients of the linear combination that represents the projection of our initial data into an m-dimensional space?